# Infinitesimal neighborhoods of an affine bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $S$ be an $\mathbb{A}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$.
We denote by $\Delta$ the diagonal of $S \times S$ (so, $\Delta \simeq S$).
Let us consider the $k$-th infinitesimal neighborhoods $\Delta_{(k)}$ of $\Delta$ in $S \times S$.

Then, my question is

> Are there any quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Delta_{(k)}$ such that $$ H^2(\Delta_{(k)}, \mathcal{F}) \neq 0 ?$$

Comment: Do you mean to ask about quasicoherent sheaves, or literally any sheaf?

Comment: I mean quasi-coherent sheaves. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If $S$ is affine, then $S \times S$ is affine, and $\Delta_{(k)} \to S \times S$ is a closed immersion (since $S/\mathbb{C}$ is separated) so $\Delta_{(k)}$ is affine as well; thus all higher cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves on $\Delta_{(k)}$ vanish right?

Comment: @MinseonShin $S$ is not affine, but $¥mathbb{A}^1$-bundle over $¥mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Y.M. Your post says "Let $S$ be an affine $\mathbb{A}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$." If you don't mean that $S$ is affine, what do you mean?

Comment: @KReiser I am sorry that I wanted to mean just affine bundle over $¥mathbb{P}^1$. For example, for $f : ¥Delta ¥rightarrow ¥mathbb{P}^1$, $H^1(¥Delta, f^*¥mathcal{O}(-2)) ¥neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is still true that $\mathrm{H}^{2}(\Delta_{(k)},\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for all quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_{(k)}}$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, the point being that $\Delta_{(k)}$ is (1) separated and (2) can be covered by two affine open subschemes. Given (1) and (2), we can use the fact that derived functor cohomology can be computed with Cech cohomology for quasi-coherent sheaves for (semi-)separated Noetherian schemes (see either Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, III, Theorem 4.5 or SP [Tag 01ET](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ET), etc).

Let $f : S \to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$ be the projection, and let $\alpha_{k} : S \to \Delta_{(k)}$ be the nilpotent closed immersion. We have $\Delta_{(0)} \simeq S$. Since $f$ is an $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-bundle morphism, it is in particular an affine morphism.

For (1), note that $f : S \to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ are separated so their composition $S \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ is separated; thus the fiber product $S \times_{\mathbb{C}} S \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ is separated, thus $\Delta_{(k)} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ is separated.

For (2), let $U_{0},U_{1} \subseteq \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$ be the standard affine open covering of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$, and set $V_{i} := f^{-1}(U_{i})$; as noted above, $f$ is an affine morphism, so each $V_{i}$ is affine. Since $\alpha_{k}$ is a nilpotent closed immersion, the underlying map of $\alpha_{k}$ is a homeomorphism; let $V_{i,(k)} \subset \Delta_{(k)}$ denote the unique open subscheme such that $\alpha_{k}^{-1}(V_{i,(k)}) = V_{i}$. Then $V_{0,(k)},V_{1,(k)}$ are open subschemes of $\Delta_{(k)}$ whose preimages in $S$ are affine; hence they themselves are affine by e.g. SP [Tag 06AD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06AD).

Comment: I am sorry for replying late, and thank you very much for your answer.
Combining with Shin's comment, can we apply Leray spectral sequence
 to $H^2(\Delta_{(k)}, \mathcal{F})$ and compare with $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1, f^{(k)}_* \mathcal{F}) = 0$ ? ($f^{(k)} : \Delta_{(k)} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$)